# Just pushed a new version of the pod to cocoapods, but can't install it

Tags: cocoapods

So I've just successfully uploaded a new release (1.0.1) of my pod (`pod trunk push MonarchRouter.podspec`), but getting this message when trying to `pod install`

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MonarchRouter":  
  In Podfile:
    MonarchRouter (~> 1.0.1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `MonarchRouter (~> 1.0.1)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I'm pretty sure it's non of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the local pod specs from here

```
~/.cocoapods/repos
```

then pod install again

Answer (score -1):

You should clean up cocoapods cache.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

*Found the answer somewhere in an unrelated thread on github, just wanted to leave it here.*